# Getting syntax error while using radiobutton in javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio1" CssClass="selectedYes" runat="server" GroupName="ImageGroup" Text="Yes" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio2" CssClass="selectedNo" runat="server" GroupName="ImageGroup" Text="No" />

<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Image ID="image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

If the image is selected and radio1 is checked value is yes then it should not be highlighted otherwise it should be highlighted. The image is in the repeater control.

```
var radio1 = $('#<%= radio1.ClientID%>');
```

gives syntax error in javascript. Please help

Comment: What is the message error outputs in your console?

Comment: How does it look when it is rendered? I mean the markup.

Comment: <INPUT tabIndex=0 id=ContentPlaceHolder1_rptTopics_rdoRequestedLicensedImageYes_1 CHECKED type=radio value=rdoRequestedLicensedImageYes name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptTopics$ctl02$Requested Licensed image" jQuery19105614982406916045="426">

Answer (score 0):

```
var radio1 = document.getElementById('"'+<%= radio1.ClientID%>+'"');
```

A different option. Just use basic javascript to find your control.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.